# NSXMLDelegate in Swift issues

Tags: ios, swift, nsxmlparserdelegate

I am trying to implement an NSXMLParserDelegate in Swift but I am having issues using the attributes dictionary in some of the delegate methods. For instance, in `parser:didStartElement:`:

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, didStartElement elementName: String!, namespaceURI: String!, qualifiedName qName: String!, attributes attributeDict: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
```

trying to access attributeDict values like:

```
if self.feedType == FeedType.RSS {
    self.insideLink = true
} else {
    if (String(attributeDict["rel"]) == "alternate") && (String(attributeDict["type"]) == "text/html") {
        self.link = String(attributeDict["href"])
        self.insideLink = false
        self.doneWithLink = true
    }
}
```

I get an error message: "'String' is not convertible to 'FeedType'".

```
enum FeedType:String {

    case ATOM = "feed"
    case RSS = "rss"

}

class FeedParser:NSObject, NSXMLParserDelegate {

    var feedType:FeedType?
```

Is an error. Same for a dozen other variations on the theme... any insights?

I guess the question is how to properly use the key / value pairs in `attributeDict` which are of type `[NSObject: AnyObject]`?

Comment: Could you post the error?

Comment: Error:'String' is not convertible to 'FeedType'.

Comment: On which line is that error reported? What are the declarations of the values used on that line?

Comment: The error is reported on the second if statement: if (String(attributeDict["rel"]) == "alternate")...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you might have a bogus error message: I'd recommend [filing a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com).

> I guess the question is how to properly use the key / value pairs in `attributeDict` which are of type `[NSObject: AnyObject]`

You're right: this looks like the root of the problem. The solution is not to *construct* a `String` from the dictionary lookup, but to (conditionally) *cast* to `String`. That is, rather than try to create a new `String` from a reference of indeterminate (and optional) type, ask Swift if that reference is actually to something that can be interpreted as a `String`:

```
let rel = attributeDict["rel"] as? String
```

That gets you an optional, both because `attributeDict` might not contain a value for the key `rel`, and because a conditional cast can fail (`attributeDict["rel"]` might be a value of a different type). Because you need to check two conditional casts and their unwrapped values, you could end up with a lot of force-unwrap operators (`!`) or deeply nested `if-let` blocks... that'd get ugly real fast.

Instead, you can take advantage of the fact that `Optional` is an enum. Its definition looks something like this:

```
enum Optional<T> {
    case None    // aka nil
    case Some(T) // what you get when you unwrap a non-nil optional
}
```

With that, you can use pattern matching to do the lookup, cast, unwrap and test safely and concisely:

```
switch (attributeDict["rel"] as? String, attributeDict["type"] as? String) {
  case let (.Some(rel), .Some(type)) where rel == "alternate" && type == "text/html":
    // harvest link
  default:
    // no match... fall back to other behavior, log an error, etc
}
```

Note that on the "harvest link" step you'll still need to conditionally cast and unwrap the `attributeDict["href"]` lookup. You could do that by nesting an `if-let` construct in that `case`, or by adding a third lookup to the `switch` tuple.

---

By the way, all the `self.` notation is unnecessary in Swift (unless you're in a closure or need to disambiguate method parameters from instance properties).

Comment: Note that while the `switch` pattern for unwrapping multiple optionals at once is still valid (and still specifically useful for certain cases), it's no longer the only way to unwrap multiple optionals at once — in [Swift 1.2 and Xcode 6.3](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=22) you can put multiple bindings in one `if let` statement.